# rspec 3.1 gem initialize error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have spent hours trying to resolve this rspec path, gem not initializing. 
What on earth does the below gibberish means? I read it out loud twice but my brain is not computing right now. Any pointers are appreciated:

```
Michel-Morels-iMac:search michelcmorel$ rspec spec/lib/zombie_spec.rb
/Users/michelcmorel/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1357:in `<class:Configuration>': uninitialized constant RSpec::Support::OS (NameError)
    from /Users/michelcmorel/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:32:in `<module:Core>'
    from /Users/michelcmorel/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:6:in `<module:RSpec>'
    from /Users/michelcmorel/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/michelcmorel/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core.rb:10:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/michelcmorel/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/michelcmorel/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-support-3.1.0/lib/rspec/support.rb:19:in `call'
    from /Users/michelcmorel/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-support-3.1.0/lib/rspec/support.rb:19:in `block in define_optimized_require_for_rspec'
    from /Users/michelcmorel/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core.rb:38:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/michelcmorel/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core.rb:38:in `each'
    from /Users/michelcmorel/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/michelcmorel/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/michelcmorel/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/michelcmorel/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/michelcmorel/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/michelcmorel/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

EDIT**
The Gemfile content is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

And Gemfile.lock content is:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.1.6)
      actionpack (= 4.1.6)
      actionview (= 4.1.6)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.1.6)
      actionview (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionview (4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    activemodel (4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.1.6)
      activemodel (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      arel (~> 5.0.0)
    activesupport (4.1.6)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
    builder (3.2.2)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.3.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.8.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.2.2)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.11)
    jbuilder (2.2.4)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (3.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.1)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mime-types (2.4.3)
    minitest (5.4.2)
    multi_json (1.10.1)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.1.6)
      actionmailer (= 4.1.6)
      actionpack (= 4.1.6)
      actionview (= 4.1.6)
      activemodel (= 4.1.6)
      activerecord (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.1.6)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.1.6)
      actionpack (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.3.2)
    rdoc (4.1.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.4)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.2)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, < 2.12)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    spring (1.1.3)
    sprockets (2.11.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.2.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.10)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.4)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.1)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.5.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  rails (= 4.1.6)
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.3)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  spring
  sqlite3
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
```

Comment: Please add your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock file. Have you recently updated any gem?

Comment: Yes I did, gem install rspec, gem install rspec-core, gem install rspec-expectations, gem install rspec-mocks (4 gems installed)

Comment: Rspec is not in your Gemfile.lock. You probably forgot to run `bundle install`. You should look up the difference between running `gem install` and using Bundler.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer came from cupakromer from Github
"Can you try dropping the other rspec-xyz gems from your Gemfile leaving only rspec-rails? It will tell bundler to require the other necessary gems. Then run bundle update rspec-rails"
It worked for me :)